# Video Skimming in HTML video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, npm

I am having a video in my Html file. I would like to add a feature say when you hover on the progress bar it should show the thumbnail of that instance of the video, same as youtube. I searched for a way and found in one that I have to set the thumbnail images for every interval in the video and in another one using some extensions like .vtt. Both are good but I want to know if we can do it in jquery or any other simple way. Does anyone have any idea how to do it in just jquery?
I referred to these libraries. [1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-sprite-thumbnails) [2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-vtt-thumbnails)

Comment: have a look at plyr.io

Comment: wow, It helped greatly. Very thanks.